# local variable 'med' referenced before assignment - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have 2 models 1) patientprofile and 2) medInfo. In the first model patientprofile, I am trying to get patients informations like (name and other personal information) and 2nd model I want to add patients Medical information data.. when I am trying check is there a existing medical information for the patient then show and update it. otherwise need to create and update it. in medinfo model using forignkey of patientprofile (id). Its working good in admin panel perfectly. but when I am trying to do it UI getting error.

below is code:view.py

```
@login_required
def medinfoupdate(request, patid):
    
    # to get patient name and id in medinfo page accessing patientprofile data
    patprofileedit = patientprofile.objects.get(id=patid)
    
    try:
        med = medInfo.objects.get(pat_ID=patid)
    
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = medInfo_form(instance=med)
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html',  {'med': med, 'form':form, 'patprofileedit' : patprofileedit} )

    except:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html',  {'patprofileedit' : patprofileedit} )


    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            form = medInfo_form(request.POST, instance=med)
            form.save()
            return redirect(patientlist)
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html', {'form': form, 'error': 'Data entered is wrong!'})
```

below is error :

```
UnboundLocalError at /medinfo/pat-11
local variable 'med' referenced before assignment
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/medinfo/pat-11
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'med' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: E:\py\patient_management_project\pmp\views.py, line 143, in medinfoupdate
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.4
Python Path:    
['E:\\py\\patient_management_project',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 12 Jun 2022 08:05:07 +0000
```

Comment: If `med = medInfo.objects.get(...)` fails then `med` will not be defined, then when the request method is "POST" this line will fail with that error `form = medInfo_form(request.POST, instance=med)`

Comment: @IainShelvington, Yes you are right!. but how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Its was working fine when there is a pat_ID exist. but when there is no pat_ID it was showing error.. for the same, I used below  method to pass pat_ID from the other model.

@login_required
def medinfoupdate(request, patid):

```
# to get patient name and id in medinfo page accessing patientprofile data
patprofileedit = patientprofile.objects.get(id=patid)
try:
    med = medInfo.objects.get(pat_ID=patid)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = medInfo_form(instance=med)
        return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html',  {'med': med,'form':form, 'patprofileedit' : patprofileedit} ) 

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            form = medInfo_form(request.POST, instance=med)
            form.save()
            return redirect(patientlist)
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html', {'form': form, 'error': 'Data entered is wrong!'})

except medInfo.DoesNotExist:
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html',  {'patprofileedit' : patprofileedit} ) 

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            form = medInfo_form(request.POST)
            newmed = form.save(commit=False)
            newmed.pat_ID = patientprofile.objects.get(id=patid)
            newmed.save()
            return redirect(patientlist)
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html', {'form': form, 'error': 'Data entered is Wrong!'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `POST` behaviour to place where `med` actually exists (and please, always add specific exception to `except`):

```
@login_required
def medinfoupdate(request, patid):
    
    # to get patient name and id in medinfo page accessing patientprofile data
    patprofileedit = patientprofile.objects.get(id=patid)
    
    try:
        med = medInfo.objects.get(pat_ID=patid)
    
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = medInfo_form(instance=med)
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html',  {'med': med, 

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                form = medInfo_form(request.POST, instance=med)
                form.save()
                return redirect(patientlist)
            except ValueError:
                return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html', {'form': form, 'error': 'Data entered is wrong!'})'form':form, 'patprofileedit' : patprofileedit} )

    except medInfo.DoesNotExist:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render(request, 'pmp/medinfo.html',  {'patprofileedit' : patprofileedit} )
```

Comment: Its working fine when there is a data in med. say for example med pat_id 16 is exist in the data table its working fine. but when there is not data in pat_id 16 I need to post data on it. how to do it?